# Wrapping of text in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, ios7, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` in which full text is not getting shown. It is getting truncated at the end.

How can I show the text in 2 or more lines?

I tried the following code but it is still showing in single line and it is not complete text.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
    // Fill the label text here
    NSString *title = @"";

    UILabel* tView = (UILabel*)view;
    if (!tView){
        CGRect frame = CGRectZero;
        tView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [tView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15]];
        tView.minimumScaleFactor = 9.0f;
        tView.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        tView.numberOfLines = 2;

        [tView setText:title];
        [tView setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    }

    return tView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I set the custom font to the app by creating category class with UIFont, the text in the UIPickerView was showing in two lines.

```
@implementation UIFont (CustomFont)

+(UIFont *)regularFontWithSize:(CGFloat)size
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:GOATHAM_FONT size:size];
}

+(UIFont *)boldFontWithSize:(CGFloat)size
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:GOATHAM_FONT size:size];
}

+(void)load
{
    SEL original = @selector(systemFontOfSize:);
    SEL modified = @selector(regularFontWithSize:);
    SEL originalBold = @selector(boldSystemFontOfSize:);
    SEL modifiedBold = @selector(boldFontWithSize:);

    Method originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, original);
    Method modifiedMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, modified);
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, modifiedMethod);

    Method originalBoldMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, originalBold);
    Method modifiedBoldMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, modifiedBold);
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalBoldMethod, modifiedBoldMethod);
}

@end
```

Also, I set font in the UIPickerView delegate method.

```
 - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

    NSString *title = @"";

    UILabel* tView = (UILabel*)view;
    if (!tView){
        CGRect frame = CGRectZero;
        tView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [tView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:GOATHAM_FONT size:14]];
        tView.minimumScaleFactor = 9.0f;
        tView.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        tView.numberOfLines = 2;

        [tView setText:title];
        [tView setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    }

    return tView;
}
```

After doing this, text was getting shown in two lines in UIPickerView.

Comment: This process doesn't seem to be working for me :/ Might you know why?

Comment: are you using other font from system font?